# Correctly aligning formula when using \mathclap

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, lists, typography, mathtools

I have some formulas where I have big simbols like `\sum` of `\bigvee` with indexes. For indexes are too long, the argument moves too far to the right:

```
\item[]\AL
\begin{flalign*}
%
&\bigvee\limits_{\substack{1\leqslant k\leqslant n\\
        1\leqslant i_1<i_1<\ldots<i_{k}\leqslant n}}
\enspace x_{i_1}x_{i_2}\cdots x_{i_{k}}.&\\ 
\end{flalign*}
```

[image: too big space]

I fix it using `\mathclap`:

```
\item[]\AL
\begin{flalign*}
%
&\bigvee\limits_{\mathclap{\substack{1\leqslant k\leqslant n\\
            1\leqslant i_1<i_1<\ldots<i_{k}\leqslant n}}}
\enspace x_{i_1}x_{i_2}\cdots x_{i_{k}}.&\\ 
\end{flalign*}
```

[image: mathclap]

But it moves to the left to much. So I try using duct tape:

```
\item[]\AL
\newlength{\mylll}%
\settowidth{\mylll}{${}_{1\leqslant i_1<i_1<\ldots<i_{k}\leqslant n}$}%
\begin{flalign*}
%
&\hspace{.5\mylll}\bigvee\limits_{\mathclap{\substack{1\leqslant k\leqslant n\\
            1\leqslant i_1<i_1<\ldots<i_{k}\leqslant n}}}
\enspace x_{i_1}x_{i_2}\cdots x_{i_{k}}.&\\ 
\end{flalign*}
```

[image]

Everything seems fine, but it is not. You can see that the formula moved right a bit more than I expected (extra spacing is marked blue):

[image]

My question is how to properly deal with such alignement without using ruler to correctly adjust the `\hspace{???}`

My MWE (**LuaLaTex**):

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
%\usepackage{showframe}
%\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in}
%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
%
\usepackage{newtxmath}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}
%
\usepackage{enumitem}


%%%%%
%Definition of a new list type
\newcounter{qcounter}
\newenvironment{questions}{
    \begin{list}{ 
            \bfseries\upshape\arabic{qcounter}.
        }{
            \renewcommand{\makelabel}[1]{%
                \textbf{\refstepcounter{qcounter}\arabic{qcounter}##1.}}%
            \usecounter{qcounter}
            \setlength{\labelwidth}{0.5em}
            \setlength{\labelsep}{0.5em}
            \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth+\labelsep+0.5em}
            \setlength{\itemsep}{2pt}
            \setlength{\listparindent}{1em}
            \setlength{\parsep}{1pt}
            \setlength{\topsep}{6pt}
        } 
    }{    
    \end{list}
}

%Command to correctly align environments in the list
\newcommand{\AL}{%
    \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\multlinegap}{0pt}%
    ~\vspace*{-\baselineskip}%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

%too big space
\item[]\AL
\begin{flalign*}
%
&\bigvee\limits_{\substack{1\leqslant k\leqslant n\\
        1\leqslant i_1<i_1<\ldots<i_{k}\leqslant n}}
\enspace x_{i_1}x_{i_2}\cdots x_{i_{k}}.&\\ 
\end{flalign*}

%too left
\item[]\AL
\begin{flalign*}
%
&\bigvee\limits_{\mathclap{\substack{1\leqslant k\leqslant n\\
            1\leqslant i_1<i_1<\ldots<i_{k}\leqslant n}}}
\enspace x_{i_1}x_{i_2}\cdots x_{i_{k}}.&\\ 
\end{flalign*}

%not very nice looking one
\item[]\AL
\newlength{\mylll}%
\settowidth{\mylll}{${}_{1\leqslant i_1<i_1<\ldots<i_{k}\leqslant n}$}%
\begin{flalign*}
%
&\hspace{.5\mylll}\bigvee\limits_{\mathclap{\substack{1\leqslant k\leqslant n\\
            1\leqslant i_1<i_1<\ldots<i_{k}\leqslant n}}}
\enspace x_{i_1}x_{i_2}\cdots x_{i_{k}}.&\\ 
\end{flalign*}

\item[]\lipsum[2]

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to load both `amsmath` *and* `mathtools`, as the latter loads the former. Furthermore, `mathtools` provides the nice command `\smashoperator`, which does precisely what you need:

```
\item[]\AL
\begin{flalign*}
%
&\smashoperator[r]{\bigvee_{\substack{1\leqslant k\leqslant n\\
            1\leqslant i_1<i_1<\ldots<i_{k}\leqslant n}}}
\enspace x_{i_1}x_{i_2}\cdots x_{i_{k}}.&\\ 
\end{flalign*}
```

You can omit the explicit call of `\limits` since `\smashoperator` automatically uses it.

From the `mathtools` documentation

> [...] `mathtools` provides a `\smashoperator` command, which simply
>   ignores the width of the sub- and superscript. It also takes an
>   optional argument, `l`, `r`, or `lr` (default), denoting which side of the
>   operator should be ignored (smashed).

Note that as long as you do not need some alignment, `flalign` is here an overkill. Just use `$\displaymath ... $`.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. What does the optional argumnet `[r]` do?

Comment: @MichaelFreimann see edit.

Comment: I get it. I also updated the question with additional problem